# Switch vote details view mode

Tags: support

Is any way to show always this view mode for myself in all stack exchange sites.

[image]

This feature is possible to view in AskUbuntu.com questions and answers I don't see this in other StackExchange sites.

Comment: @iStimple Thank you, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't.

Also showing the vote breakdown for all posts (even for some users) would be a significant performance hit.

Comment: Just for my view not to other user.

Comment: @KasiyA - even for your view.